# Trouble saving current state of css class in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using two buttons to toggle css classes that either show or hide a background. I would like to save the current state of each class in local storage and display (or not display) them when the user returns. I have made an attempt with the `wrapping` class in this jsFiddle, but I don't have it working yet:

http://jsfiddle.net/eqrk6fak/1/

Setting it like so:

```
    $("#switch2").click(function() {        
    wrap.fadeToggle(600);
    if($('div').hasClass(wrap)){
    localStorage.setItem('background', wrap);
    }
});
```

And then trying to get it when the user returns:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var background = localStorage.getItem('background');  
if(background !== ''){      
    $('#wraping').addClass(background);
}
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line:

```
$('div').hasClass(wrap)
```

Reviewing your JSFiddle code, at that point `wrap` is a jQuery result:

```
var wrap = $(".wraping");
```

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), `jquery.hasClass` receives a `className` which should be a `String`.